# JAVA Retrive current bitcoin price with JSON

Tags: java, json, bitcoin

I want to get current/historical bitcoin price by using JSON..

However, the code shows a following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at RwithJlab.Basic.main(Basic.java:19)
```

---------------------------------code---------------------------------

```
package RwithJlab;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Basic 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException
    {
        JSONObject data = getJSONfromURL("https://blockchain.info/charts/market-price?format=json");
        JSONArray data_array = data.getJSONArray("values");

        for (int i = 0; i < ((CharSequence) data_array).length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject price_point = (JSONObject) data_array.get(i);

            //  Unix time
            int x = price_point.getInt("1364062505");

            //  Bitcoin price at that time
            double y = price_point.getDouble("y");

            //  Do something with x and y.
            System.out.println(x);

        }

    }

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String URL) throws JSONException
    {
        try
        {
            URLConnection uc;
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            uc = url.openConnection();
            uc.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
            uc.connect();

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream(), 
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int cp;
            while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1)
            {
                sb.append((char)cp);
            }

            String jsonText = (sb.toString());            

            return new JSONObject(jsonText.toString());
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should at least log Exceptions when you catch them, otherwise you are out of clue when that exception occurs.

In your case you are catching an `IOException` and returning `null`. This results in a `NullPointerException` later, but you cannot see the root cause.

Log that `IOException` (at least call `ex.printStackTrace()`) and you will see the real reason.

Comment: You should see the stacktrace before NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You get `JSONException` at line `int x = price_point.getInt("1364062505");`

First of all, look at the source JSON from the [URL](https://api.blockchain.info/charts/market-price?format=json) you are trying to retrieve.

It's structure is:

```
values: [ {x : timestamp, y : value}, ... ]
```

Where ***timestamp*** is a representaion of the date in millis and ***value*** is the price of BTC in USD.

You're trying to `getInt("1364062505")` while such key in `values` JSON array does not exist.

`JSONException` is thrown at `getInt(key)` if the key is not found or if the value cannot be converted to an integer ([look here](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt-java.lang.String-)).

You need to write `int x = price_point.getInt("x")`, or even better - replace your `getInt()` to `optInt()` and `getDouble()` to `optDouble()`. In this case you won't get any exceptions, only a zero, if such key in `JSONObject` does not exist. Then you should  check your values in `if (value != 0)` block